Crew of thieves trapped in a 7-chamber maze
The crew of thieves were convinced to a rob an item in the house they break into, After they break into the house it appeared that they get trapped in a  7 room/chamber maze/riddle and to get to the goal they have to pass from one room to another. I don't remember any more details to add to this even my copy from 1997 was cut somewhere after 4th chamber.
I guess it was USA. I think it can be even early 80s. I reminded myself one more thing - they escape from one chamber by destroying one big brick on the floor level.

Language country - I was 13 so I can guess it was USA. I think it can be even early 80'. I reminded myself one more thing - they escape from one chamber by destroying one big brick on the floor level.

Might be Beyond the 7th Door from 1987 about a robber convincing his ex-girlfriend to steal a treasure from her employer's mansion. Other than the fact that there are only two of them, the rest fits: Once they break in, they find themselves trapped in a 7-chamber maze and have to solve various riddles to survive. And here's a clip from the movie where the Tommy Wiseau-like hero breaks a big chunk in a brick wall:




Yes, this is it. I thought that there were more people, but yeah, I have seen part of this movie more than 20 years ago. I don't know how do you find theses movies. But also "7" is common in title which I know from title: "7th chamber".
